# How to find a compatible AC adapter for my external HDDs?

Tags: external-hard-drive, ac-adapter

I have 2 external HDDs, from which I lost the AC adapters. One is Seagate and the other one is Toshiba. How can I find power adapters for them that are fully compatible?

Comment: You need to know two things about your external hard drives that are missing their AC power adapters: manufacturer and serial number. When I tried to find a power adapter for my WD external HDD which has its serial number printed on the back the first Google search result was this webpage: [Power Adapters for WD Products](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=1378). Adapter Type and Currently Shipping Compatible Adapter status is listed for the adapters. Try the same for your external HDDs and comment about the results.

Comment: one is toshiba the other is seagate :\

Answer (score 1):

First option, search for "devicename devicemodel# power adapter" on ebay. You might find actual genuine branded used adapters for that exact device.  You will also probably find 3rd party adapters for the device being sold by sellers in China. The 3rd party adapters will probably work OK but may not be as good quality.

Second option.   You can buy generic power adapters that can be used with a wide variety of devices.  They come with a selection of plugs (pick the one that fits your device) and a dial on the adapter to adjust the output voltage. As long as the output voltage can be dialed to match and the output milliamps is equal or greater than that from the original adapter, it will work.  If you go this route, get one sold by a recognized brand name, and not a white box label.  Everything is made in China, but you want something that has actually been made with quality control and has actually passed certifications for safety and power efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know two things about your external hard drives that are missing their AC power adapters: manufacturer and serial number, which are usually printed on the back of the external HDD. I searched for power adapters for Seagate and Toshiba external HDDs and they didn't have their own manufacturer's webpage like WD external hard drives have, however when I searched again for power adapters for Seagate (Seagate external hard drive) and Toshiba (Toshiba external hard drive) HDDs I found them at this webpage: [MyVolts - Power supplies and other powering solutions](https://myvolts.com/MV_search).

Many of the available power adapters have AC100-240V, 50/60Hz input voltage. Make sure that this is compatible with your requirements.